# Order of defining models in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have some problem with order of defining models in django,so i want some thing like this :

```
class Album(models.Model):
   mainTrack = models.OneToOneField(Track)


class Track(models.Model):
   albumID = models.ForeignKey(Album)
```

and in this way when i want run makemigration command,django give this error:

```
Track is not defined
```

there is exist any way to solve that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already noticed this line

```
mainTrack = models.OneToOneField(Track)
```

references `Track` but obviously `Track` is not defined at this time.

**Solution:**

Reference to the `Track` model using a string:

```
mainTrack = models.OneToOneField('Track')
```

This is also mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `related_name="track"` to your `ForeignKey` call.

```
class Album(models.Model):
    mainTrack = models.OneToOneField(Track)

class Track(models.Model):
    albumID = models.ForeignKey('Album', related_name="track")
```

Comment: You would need to include some description on how this code helps.